# UITableView as a menu with dynamic row number

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that serves as a menu (user picks a row and fires a segue). Currently my code looks like:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self isAuthorized]) {
        if ([self isAdmin]) {
            return 7;
        }
        return 5;
    } else {
        return 4;
    }
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self isAuthorized]) {
        if ([self isAdmin]) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                // code 1
            } else (indexPath.row == 1) { {
                // code 2
            } // etc...
        } else {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                // code 1
            } else (indexPath.row == 1) { {
                // code 2
            } // etc...
        }
    } else {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            // code 1
        } else (indexPath.row == 1) { {
            // code 2
        } // etc...
    }
}
```

is it possible to tie action initiated by cell with a cell, so `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` looks simplier?

Comment: or you should create a dictionary, with 2 keys: isAdmin, notAdmin; at each key add an array with your cellsData and get the data from dictionary in another array -> menuDataSource; in numberOfRows allways return the [menuDataSource count];
in your dictionary add a key:tag; and bassed on the tag value; in didSelectRow do something.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your custom UITableViewCell classes and try doing the following:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass: [AdminCellClass class]])
    {
        //code here
    }
    else if
        ...
}
```